# condition's statement gets skipped

Tags: bash

i am new to scripting.how do i correct this bash script. for all values it gives me the "else" condition - "wrong value"

```
     #!/bin/bash
     read -p "First Name: " $first
     read -p "Last Name: " $last
     read -p "profession 1 for software and 2 for hardware (1/2): " $pro
     echo $first
     if [ "$pro" == "1" ];then
        echo $first
        echo $last
     elif [ "$pro" == "2" ];then
     echo $first
     echo $last
     echo $pro
     else
        echo "wrong value!"
    fi
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: you need to pass the variable name to `read` without a dollar sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change …

```
read -p "First Name: " $first
read -p "Last Name: " $last
read -p "profession 1 for software and 2 for hardware (1/2): " $pro
```

… to …

```
read -p "First Name: " first
read -p "Last Name: " last
read -p "profession 1 for software and 2 for hardware (1/2): " pro
```

Note the lack of `$` on `first`, `last` and `pro`.  In shell you do not use the `$` on a variable when assigning it a value.

Comment: Further explanation: you use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, but not to *set* it. E.g. `read varname`, `varname=value`, etc. BTW, you should also use double-quotes around variable references, e.g. `echo "$pro"` instead of just `echo $pro`.

Comment: More information (and probably more information than you want): if `first` isn't set, then `read $first` is equivalent to `read`, which implicitly uses the variable `REPLY` to store the input. If `first` *is* set, then the expansion produces one (or possibly more) words to use as variables. For instance, `first=foo; read $first` sets the variable `foo`. `first="foo bar"; read $first` would set the variables `foo` and `bar` after performing word-splitting on the input. All of this is to say, it's not *wrong* to use `read $first`; it just doesn't do what you expected. :)